# Creating a crontab that executes a php script and 1 hour later removes itself

Tags: php, cron

I'm trying to create a phpscript that creates a crontab that starts an application and shuts it down after 1 hour. I've figured out how to start the application and how to kill the process. All that is left is creating the cronjob, executing it 1 hour from now and it removing itself.
Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you thought about using the `at` daemon? It is not as popular as `cron` but does exactly what you want: run a certain command a single time at a particular point in time.

If you can execute shell scripts on the server you might be able to write a shell script that runs the program in background, sleeps for 1h and stops it afterwards if necessary. This would reduce the number of at/cron queue items.

Comment: If I use "at" to do something 1 hour in the future, Will it keep doing it every hour or will it remove itself after it's used?

Comment: With `at` you put commands onto a queue and after execution the commands are deleted. Thus they are run once which should meet your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

To start the application simply create a crontab:

```
crontab -e
```

In your command prompt.  Then write the crontab with the time you want it to start and the path to where the php script is stored:

```
10 10 * * * /Users/you/phpinhere/myphp.php &> /Users/you/output
```

You can direct it to an output file so then you can read if there area any errors etc.
Then do another cron underneath your first one for an hour later, and run the script to kill it.

Comment: I think you have mistaken me, I want the phpfile to create the cron.

Answer (score 0):

I would create 2 cron jobs: One starts the process and one will kill it one hour later.

Comment: If I kill that cron process, will it kill the child process too?

Comment: I wanted to say something else: I would start a cron job, that really does nothing more, than starting the script I want to run and then terminates. The second cron tab will then kill the script process.

Comment: Why would the first cron be necessary then? I can just use shell_exec in php to start the bash script.

Comment: Of course you can, but as you started talking about crons I expected, that the script should startup at a given time, or in specific intervals (and thats what cron jobs good for).